# Magento 2 static content deploy command shows error

Tags: magento2

```
php -f magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

While running this command after making css changes in the theme file of the **magento 2** I got the below error

```
ubuntu@tlttvmd42:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/bin$ php -f magento setup:static-content:deploy
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Json\json_decode() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php:152
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(269): Composer\Json\JsonFile->validateSchema(1)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(532): Composer\Factory->createComposer(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), '/opt/lampp/htdo...', false)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerFactory.php(47): Composer\Factory::create(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), '/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(362): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerFactory->create()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(375): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getComposer()
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(242): Magento\F in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php on line 152
```

And I googled it and there are some suggestion to install `Php` `json` and I found in the `phpinfo Json` is already enabled

I used the suggessted command to install the json

```
sudo apt-get install php-json
```

Once installing I restarted the Lampp and i tried to deploy the static **Magento** command and I still face the same issue, Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I use Ubutu Os and Lampp server

Comment: try this sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: try this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: try this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, but you do not have to be in the "bin" folder, you to be in Magento root folder

Comment: i tried the below command as you mentioned above inside the magento root folder                              ubuntu@tlttvmd42:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ecom$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ,
But i still face the above mentioend error

Comment: refer this link may be it is use full to you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode)

Comment: I guess problem is due to the PHP version 7.0.2 with Magento 2 , Thanks for the above link , i will try downgrading the php version and let know if it worked

Comment: It can be also occurs due to multiple php present into your system so first try only with the **php version 7.0.2**

To remove the other php run this command `sudo apt-get remove php5-json`

To install the newer Php 7 Jason run this command
`apt-get update`
`apt-get install php7.0-json`

Answer (score 0):

You try this sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy after no any error solve your var folder remove it and after this command try it.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this issue by uninstalling multiple PHP versions and reinstall fresh PHP 7 version and the above command now working fine, Thankyou all for the sugesstions.